# Getting error while running the CodeIgniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error while running one existing CodeIgniter application on my ubuntu server.

> **Error:**
>
> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Exception
>
> Message: Session: Configured save path
>   '/var/www/oditek.in/PHPTravels1/system/cache' is not writable by the
>   PHP process.
>
> Filename:
>   /var/www/oditek.in/PHPTravels1/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 143

I am providing my code below.

index.php:

```
<?php

    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');

    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(-1);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;
        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            ini_set('display_errors', 0);
            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
            {
                error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
            }
            else
            {
                error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
            }
        break;
        default:
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
            exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
    }

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do,
 * use an absolute (full) server path.
 * For more info please see the user guide:
 *
 * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view directory out of the application
 * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application directory.
 * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';


/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" directory.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-directory within the "controllers" one
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = strtr(
            rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system directory
    define('BASEPATH', $system_path);


    // Path to the front controller (this file) directory
    define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // Name of the "system" directory
    define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));

    // The path to the "application" directory
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $application_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
            trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // The path to the "views" directory
    if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
    }
    elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $view_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
            trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

application/config/config.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'en';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.,:_\-\'';
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '73L1DmftGB1OOCYOTb3KPPhAJJz8J5jiH';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] =  BASEPATH . 'cache/';
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'pt_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
$config['is_offline'] = TRUE;
```

When I am running this application on my Ubuntu server, I am getting the above error.

Comment: `Configured save path '/var/www/oditek.in/PHPTravels1/system/cache' is not writable by the PHP process` seems quite clear: make that folder writable by your PHP process. Look up [chmod](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change permissions of "/var/www/oditek.in/PHPTravels1/system/cache" directory to 664 (RW RW R)(create that directory if it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

The User on which ur process is running needs  write permission to the cache folder