# Getting Error 505, unable to run my website

Tags: php

I have problem with an Admin Panel I downloaded from the Internet. I did upload it to DreamHost and paid for domain and plan. :) All files has been uploaded,but I keep getting the same error 500 when I open the URL of the page. 
DreamHost has been contacted and they help me a lot - the problem does not come from the server nor from the connection to the database. I would be really greateful if you guys can help me.

Index page(I believe the error is somewhere here)

```
<?php

define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production');

switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
case 'development':
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
break;

case 'testing':
case 'production':
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>=')) {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    } else {
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
    }
break;

default:
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', true, 503);
    echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
    exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

$system_path = 'system';

$application_folder = 'application';

$view_folder = '';

if (defined('STDIN')) {
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
}

if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== false) {
    $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
} else {
    $system_path = strtr(
        rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}

// Is the system path correct?
if (!is_dir($system_path)) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', true, 503);
    echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

// The name of THIS file
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

// Path to the system directory
define('BASEPATH', $system_path);

// Path to the front controller (this file) directory
define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Name of the "system" directory
define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));

// The path to the "application" directory
if (is_dir($application_folder)) {
    if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== false) {
        $application_folder = $_temp;
    } else {
        $application_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
} elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) {
    $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
        trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    );
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', true, 503);
    echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.self;
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// The path to the "views" directory
if (!isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) {
    $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
} elseif (is_dir($view_folder)) {
    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== false) {
        $view_folder = $_temp;
    } else {
        $view_folder = strtr(
            rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
} elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) {
    $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
        trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
        '/\\',
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
    );
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', true, 503);
    echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.self;
    exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
}

define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

**Here is the user I use to manage the database**

[image]

**And the database connection**

[image]

Comment: server See error_log fle you should be able to see what causing that error

Answer (score 0):

Please check the PHP version of the server. Check the CodeIgniter Server Requirements https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/requirements.html

If server requirements are meet then open the **application/config/config.php** file and set **Error Logging Threshold** value **1**

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Now, you will see the PHP related errors on the application/logs directory.

Comment: The server is 7.2 and above. I just changed this line and nothing happened..Still shows 500 error

Comment: Did you set the .htaccess? You can follow the documentation https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file
If you did. Then I think it is htaccess rewrite issue.
Please configure the htaccess rewrite and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read error from error_log file, you probably having an error from `.htaccess` file.

But in case you can check every line of your code to see what causing error.

Folowing example will give you an idea how to do that and its a working example.

Please read comments in codes

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT')){
    switch (ENVIRONMENT){
      case 'development':
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
      break;

      case 'testing':
      case 'production':
       error_reporting(0);
      break;

      default:
       exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
$system_path = '/sitefolder/system';
$application_folder = '/sitefolder/application';

// Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
if (defined('STDIN')){
  chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
}

if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE){
  $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
}

// ensure there's a trailing slash
$system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

// Is the system path correct?
if (!is_dir($system_path)){
  exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
}

// The name of THIS file
define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

// The PHP file extension
// this global constant is deprecated you can comment it or remove.
define('EXT', '.php');

// Path to the system folder
define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

// Name of the "system folder"
define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


// The path to the "application" folder
if (is_dir($application_folder)){
  define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}else{
  if (!is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/')){
   exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
  }

  define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

**Attention :** you might need to change permissions on folders or directory

And your `.htaccess` should be something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ yoursitefolder/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

See this question for complete example [Getting error while running the CodeIgniter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113679/getting-error-while-running-the-codeigniter-application)

See here for error 500 : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem ^.^ It was the database connection...